# does jQuery support OR in selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if jQuery can do something like this or is there another way to do this?

```
$(".row_c:last|.row_d:last").css("color","red");
```

I have alternating rows that I want to find the last row which is either row_c or row_d  however the catch is that row_c or row_d is inserted in between another set of alternating rows row_a and row_b so to illustrate:

- row_a
- row_b
- row_c
- row_d
- row_c <-- need to find this
- row_a
- row_b

OR

- row_a
- row_b
- row_c
- row_d <-- need to find this
- row_a
- row_b

can we use the | or operator in jQuery? Or is there something similar?

Comment: You could also use a regular expression, `^row_[cd]`

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I believe it does, but in a CSS manner ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZxA5/) as a proof):

```
$(".row_c:last, .row_d:last").css("color","red");
```

**EDIT:**

If you wanted to match only last element having class `row_c` or `row_d`, you may wish to use something like that ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZxA5/1/) as a proof):

```
$(".row_c, .row_d").last().css("color","red");
```

Comment: this approach applies it to both of the last classes, not either or

Comment: Perfect! i wasn't thinking out of the box enough! Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Just use comma as separator for different selectors:

```
$(".row_c ~ .row_d", ".row_d ~ .row_c").css("color","red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mixing your logic concepts a bit there. To do a simple `or`, you just separate your selectors with a comma:

```
$(".this, .orThat") // looks for items with one or the other (or both) classes
```

An `and` would be to combine them:

```
$(".thisClass.andThisClass") // looks for an item with both classes
```

But I don't think that's what you are looking for. You are looking for a specific pair of rows and want to act upon the second item.

I'd do something like this:

```
$(".row_d").next(".row_c").dosomething
```

Comment: $(".this, .orThat") applies whatever to both this AND that in my case. Also, the Next does it to both of the last ones as well.

Comment: ah, sorry, yea that last example isn't quite what you were looking for.